# Jquery UI Tab navigation with arrow in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-tabs

Hi I'm trying to make a down arrow for a Jquery UI Tab Navigation in active state something like this.

[image]

It's currently working fine without the down arrow. I've seen this tread [Jquery UI Tab with Arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094197/jquery-ui-tabs-how-to-represent-an-active-tab-using-a-down-arrow-instead-of-t) but my HTML div class doesn't have the class "active" for the li element. Can someone kindly advise me what would be the solution for this? Thank you!

```
<div class="menuArea">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#activeTap" data-tab-name="activeTab">ACTIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#inactiveTap" data-tab-name="inactiveTab">INACTIVE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS for the jquery ui-tabs.

```
.ui-tabs {

    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.ui-tabs-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background:url("../images/gradient_default.gif") repeat-x;
}
.ui-tabs-nav li {
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.ui-tabs-active {
    background:url("../images/gradient_active.gif");
    font-weight:bold;
}

.ui-tabs-active a {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions to your problem.

1) You can make the arrow part of the background image for the active link. This will likely require tweaks to your css.

2) You can include the arrow inside the `a` by using the `img` tag and relatively positioning it.

`<a href="#activeTap" data-tab-name="activeTab">ACTIVE<img src="path/to/arrow.png" /></a>`

```
position:relative;
top:/*some value*/;
left:/*some value*/;
```

The downside of this - if you care - is that it becomes semantically confusing using css background image and an img.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't fully understand what you're talking about.. how does it suppose to work if user clicks the INACTIVE TAB? Will it show the arrow in that state as well??